# rails temporary variable to pass to model for processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube

hi i'm useing rails 4  with ruby 2. im trying to create youtube_uri variable to pass it to model to extract v variable and to get lenght of video. it should be something like temp in model

what i did:

```
  def youtube_uri=(input_data)
        puts "youtube nuoroda imesta"
        query_string = URI.parse(input_data).query
        parameters = Hash[URI.decode_www_form(query_string)]
        self.youtube = parameters['v']
        url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/#{self.youtube}?v=2"
        data = RestClient.get url
        data = XmlSimple.xml_in(data, { 'KeyAttr' => 'name' })
        self.youtube_lenght = data['group'][0]['duration'][0]['seconds']
  end
```

so in view i should be able to use :youtube_uri, but it throws me an error:

```
undefined method `youtube_uri' for #<News:0x007f9cd207b838>
<%= f.text_field :youtube_uri %>
```

what do i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `youtube_uri` as `attr_reader` in your model:

```
class News < AR::Base
  attr_reader :youtube_uri
  ...
end
```

This will create a getter `youtube_uri`.  What you've done is only defined the setter, but when you use it as:

```
<%= f.text_field :youtube_uri %>
```

the form helper is looking for the method `youtube_uri`.